# jQuery: filter out elements via class?

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a website featuring a long list of names.
To make it more oversee-able, I'd like to put a text link in to

(on load) show all

(on clicking word "pears") hide all elements with class="apple"

(on clicking word "apples") hide all elements with class="pear"

(on clicking "show all") show all

I suppose it'd be like a really simplified version of "as you type" filtering.

Does a plug-in exist for this? I don't even know where to start!

Answer (score 28):

Just bumped into this post, I know it's old but to be honest are none of the given answers pretty helpful. In my opinion, you can filter out the elements using the filter with *:not*, as in `filter(':not()')`.

As *Joel Potter* stated, using `$("span[class='apple']").hide();` will only select the spans with exactly one classname, *apple*. If multiple classes are present (which is highly likely) then such an approach would not work.

If you click on a word, e.g. *pears*, you can then filter out the elements that do *not* contain the class `pears`.

```
$('span').show().filter(':not(.pears)').hide();
```

and you're done ;)

Comment: If you want to filter more than one element remember to use this syntax: `$('span').show().filter(':not(.pears, .apples, .oranges, .etc)').hide();`

Answer (score 23):

hmm.. if you had a list like the following:

```
<span class="apple">red apple</span>
<span class="apple">green apple</span>
<span class="pear">big pear</span>
<span class="pear">little pear</span>
```

the following would show all:

```
$("span.*").show();
```

the following would hide all elements with 'class="apple"':

```
$("span[class='apple']").hide();
```

or you could go with hiding everything that doesn't have 'class="pear"':

```
$("span[class!='pear']").hide();
```

Comment: "span[class='apple']" would select spans with ONLY apple in the class. You should use "span.apple" so you could have class="apple fruit".

Comment: Or just $(".apple").hide(); for example

Answer (score 19):

To filter out elements that contain a given class or any other attribute value, using the [Attribute Contains Word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/) would be a good solution:

```
$("span").filter("[class~='apple']")
```

Actually, for the class attribute, it's even easier to just write:

```
$("span").filter(".apple") // or:
$("span.apple")
```

[This is also what Joel Potter wrote in his comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/879959/177710).]

That way you'll be able to match all of the below:

```
<span class="apple">...</span>
<span class="apple fruit">...</span>
<span class="fruit apple sweet">...</span>
```

So whenever you're not 100% sure that you'll only have a single class set on an element, use the `~=` operator.

Comment: Underrated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out elements via CSS selector with the jQuery [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) function.

So for instance, to get all elements that aren't pears you can do:

```js
$("*").not(".pear")
```